# TicTacToe Check For Draw

Tags: java, user-interface, tic-tac-toe

Wrote a TicTacToe game with a GUI using JButtons. Below is the code used to check if there is a winner. Also included is my code to check for a draw. HOWEVER, on the event that all buttons are clicked AND the last move results in a win for one of the players, it is still considered a draw due to all of the buttons being clicked. How can I fix it so that it will accurately check for a draw?

```
public void checkWin(char[] values)
{
    //Check if player 1 (xs) win
    if ((values[0] == 'x') && (values[1] == 'x') && (values[2] == 'x'))
    {
        playerLabel.setText("Player 1 wins!");
        disableButtons();
    }
    else if ((values[3] == 'x') && (values[4] == 'x') && (values[5] == 'x'))
    {
        playerLabel.setText("Player 1 wins!");
        disableButtons();
    }
    else if ((values[6] == 'x') && (values[7] == 'x') && (values[8] == 'x'))
    {
        playerLabel.setText("Player 1 wins!");
        disableButtons();
    }
    else if ((values[0] == 'x') && (values[4] == 'x') && (values[8] == 'x'))
    {
        playerLabel.setText("Player 1 wins!");
        disableButtons();
    }
    else if ((values[2] == 'x') && (values[4] == 'x') && (values[6] == 'x'))
    {
        playerLabel.setText("Player 1 wins!");
        disableButtons();
    }
    else if ((values[0] == 'x') && (values[3] == 'x') && (values[6] == 'x'))
    {
        playerLabel.setText("Player 1 wins!");
        disableButtons();
    }
    else if ((values[1] == 'x') && (values[4] == 'x') && (values[7] == 'x'))
    {
        playerLabel.setText("Player 1 wins!");
        disableButtons();
    }
    else if ((values[2] == 'x') && (values[5] == 'x') && (values[8] == 'x'))
    {
        playerLabel.setText("Player 1 wins!");
        disableButtons();
    }
    // check for draw
    else if (((values[0] == 'x') || (values[0] == 'o')) && ((values[1] == 'x') || (values[1] == 'o')) &&
    ((values[2] == 'x') || (values[2] == 'o')) && ((values[3] == 'x') || (values[3] == 'o')) && ((values[4] == 'x') || (values[4] == 'o'))
    && ((values[5] == 'x') || (values[5] == 'o')) && ((values[6] == 'x') || (values[6] == 'o')) && ((values[7] == 'x') || (values[7] == 'o'))
    && ((values[8] == 'x') || (values[8] == 'o')))
    {
        playerLabel.setText("DRAW!");
        disableButtons();
    }

    //Check is player 2 (os) wins
    if ((values[0] == 'o') && (values[1] == 'o') && (values[2] == 'o'))
    {
        playerLabel.setText("Player 2 wins!");
        disableButtons();
    }
    else if ((values[3] == 'o') && (values[4] == 'o') && (values[5] == 'o'))
    {
        playerLabel.setText("Player 2 wins!");
        disableButtons();
    }
    else if ((values[6] == 'o') && (values[7] == 'o') && (values[8] == 'o'))
    {
        playerLabel.setText("Player 2 wins!");
        disableButtons();
    }
    else if ((values[0] == 'o') && (values[4] == 'o') && (values[8] == 'o'))
    {
        playerLabel.setText("Player 2 wins!");
        disableButtons();
    }
    else if ((values[2] == 'o') && (values[4] == 'o') && (values[6] == 'o'))
    {
        playerLabel.setText("Player 2 wins!");
        disableButtons();
    }
    else if ((values[0] == 'o') && (values[3] == 'o') && (values[6] == 'o'))
    {
        playerLabel.setText("Player 2 wins!");
        disableButtons();
    }
    else if ((values[1] == 'o') && (values[4] == 'o') && (values[7] == 'o'))
    {
        playerLabel.setText("Player 2 wins!");
        disableButtons();
    }
    else if ((values[2] == 'o') && (values[5] == 'o') && (values[8] == 'o'))
    {
        playerLabel.setText("Player 2 wins!");
        disableButtons();
    }
    // check for draw
    else if (((values[0] == 'x') || (values[0] == 'o')) && ((values[1] == 'x') || (values[1] == 'o')) &&
    ((values[2] == 'x') || (values[2] == 'o')) && ((values[3] == 'x') || (values[3] == 'o')) && ((values[4] == 'x') || (values[4] == 'o'))
    && ((values[5] == 'x') || (values[5] == 'o')) && ((values[6] == 'x') || (values[6] == 'o')) && ((values[7] == 'x') || (values[7] == 'o'))
    && ((values[8] == 'x') || (values[8] == 'o')))
    {
        playerLabel.setText("DRAW!");
        disableButtons();
    }
}
```

Comment: So... there's definitely a better way of doing things then checking every possible combination. Going with what you've got though, if you get through all the if statements, why do you need to check for a draw at all? If every box is checked and you make it that far, isn't there a draw by default?

Comment: The other option is that all boxes are blank, such as when starting a new game. Also simply making an else statement will make the game draw all the time.

Comment: Then create a boolean variable that determines if the game has started and set it to false after the first move. If the game will draw all the time with an else statement, the conditional logic in your code needs some work.

Answer (score 0):

Just check for all winning scenarios, then in the last `else` statement it should be a draw...

```
else{
  playerLabel.setText("DRAW!");
  disableButtons();
}
```

On another note, you can really shorten your code here by creating a generic method and passing it the appropriate arguments..This code is very cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

You could use some functions and loops:

```
public void checkGameOver(char[] values) {
    if (checkWin(values, 'x')) {
        playerLabel.setText("Player 1 wins!");
    } else if (checkWin(values, 'o')) {
        playerLabel.setText("Player 2 wins!");
    } else if (checkDraw(values)) {
        playerLabel.setText("DRAW");
    } else {
        return;
    }

    disableButtons();
}

public boolean checkWins(char[] values, char player) {
    if (((values[0] == player) && (values[1] == player) && (values[2] == player)) ||
        ((values[3] == player) && (values[4] == player) && (values[5] == player)) ||
        ((values[6] == player) && (values[7] == player) && (values[8] == player)) ||
        ((values[0] == player) && (values[4] == player) && (values[8] == player)) ||
        ((values[2] == player) && (values[4] == player) && (values[6] == player)) ||
        ((values[0] == player) && (values[3] == player) && (values[6] == player)) || 
        ((values[1] == player) && (values[4] == player) && (values[7] == player)) ||
        ((values[2] == player) && (values[5] == player) && (values[8] == player)))
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public boolean checkDraw(char[] values) {
    for (char c : values) { // check if each box holds either an 'x' or an 'o'
        if (c != 'o' && c != 'x') {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by:

1 - you use a String text variable that stores the text that needs to be setted on the player label.

2 - on each if, you set text variable according to the text that needs to be setted, for example on the ifs that the player 1 wins, you put text = "PLAYER 1 WINS".

3 - you only set the player label once, on the end of the method, and not in each "if" as you put on the code above.

4- Use two boolean variables, like boolean player1=false, player2=false. And when player1 wins, its set to true, otherwise false. The same applies to player2. In other words, on each if that for example the player 1 wins, you put player1=true.

5- In the end, you just need to check, if both player1 and  player2 variable is true, then its draw. (And dont forget to set the variable text = "DRAW").